# Why did Jimmy Hoffa never order the killing of Tony Pro?

Tags: the-irishman

In the movie **The Irishman** we can see a lot of quarrel between Jimmy Hoffa and Tony Pro, many a time Tony Pro almost beat Hoffa to the ground. But it seems very illogical to me why Hoffa being a very powerful man (*nobody threatens Hoffa*) always gave up with Tony Pro? I understand that Tony Pro was a capo for Genovese Family but Hoffa had enormous wealth and Genovese could kill one of their Capo for the money. Was it because Tony Pro was Italian? As in Goodfellas, it is stated that no one kills Family's wiseguys, not even to think if he is Italian.

Coming to the main question, when Hoffa says to Frank on phone "I can't meet with that little guy, only two of you come" (I'm sorry for not stating the dialogue in verbatim) to which Frank replies "It is not possible". I mean why couldn't Tony Pro be handled?

So, I’m restating my question:

**Why couldn't Hoffa whack Tony Pro out?**

Any personal thoughts derived from the movie and sources like **I Heard you Paint Houses** will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas Jimmy Hoffa was indeed a very powerful man with mob ties, he himself was not a mobster. He was a real (not nominal) top manager for Teamsters, not a head of a crime family.

Whereas he was not a saint (jury tampering, fraud etc.), getting people whacked never was his way of solving problems.